# Block I/O in InputStream's read()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, io, inputstream

I'm trying to write an algorithm, that downloads a video live stream. Specifically, the respective stream I'm trying to fetch is based on a dynamic **.m3u8** playlist file, which periodically provides URIs of new video files. The main goal is to combine those individual media files into one coherent InputStream.
I actually succeeded in getting it to work: I periodically check for new media files, that appear inside the playlist, and pass their HTTP streams to a custom InputStream implementation, namely [InputStreamChain](http://paranoid-engineering.blogspot.de/2008/11/inputstreamchain.html). Since it's a live stream, I assume it to be *endless*, at least for the time being. Ergo, I wanted my `InputStreamChain`'s `read()` never to send the -1. Unfortunately, it did; every time when all queued media streams were consumed, the `InputStreamChain` ended. Instead, I wanted it to block I/O, until a new media file arrives.
So, I came up with a working solution: I adjusted the `read()` method to loop until there's a new stream available (a `TimerTask` will provide the new files). In the loop, I built in a `Thread.sleep()`, in order to reduce the CPU load:

```
public int read() throws IOException {  
    int bit = current.read();  
    if (bit == -1 && streams.size() > 0) {  
        // left out due to lacking relevance
    } else if(bit == -1 && streams.size() == 0) {
        while(streams.size() == 0) {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(50);
        }
        return read();
    }
    return bit;
}
```

Although it seems to work, I have a feeling, that I'm not doing it how I'm supposed to. I also tried using `Lock` together with `Condition.await()`, but when my `TimerTask` tried to trigger `Condition.signal()`, it just threw a `IllegalMonitorStateException`.
That's why I'm asking the **question**:

In what way should I delay/block an InputStream's `read()` method, especially in my scenario?

**Edit:**

For the sake of completeness, I'm going to provide my failed `Lock` approach, too:

```
private ReentrantLock ioLock;
private Condition ioCond;
private boolean waitingForStream = false;

public InputStreamChain() {
    ioLock = new ReentrantLock();
    ioCond = ioLock.newCondition();
}

public synchronized InputStreamChain addInputStream(final InputStream stream) {
    streams.addLast(stream);
    if (current == null) {
        current = streams.removeFirst();
    }
    if(waitingForStream) {
        ioCond.signal();
    }
    return this;
}

public int read() throws IOException {
    int bit = current.read();
    if (bit == -1 && streams.size() > 0) {
        // do stuff
    } else if(bit == -1) {
        waitingForStream = true;
        ioLock.lock();
        try {
            ioCond.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            waitingForStream = false;
            ioLock.unlock();
        }
        return read();
    }
    return bit;
}
```

Comment: You must acquire the lock both to signal the condition and to wait for the condition.

Comment: @Flavio I wrote down my `Lock` approach off the top of my head. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You must call `lock.lock()` before `cond.signal()`, and then `lock.unlock()`.

Comment: I checked now the rest of the code: build the condition as soon as the lock, and don't ever reassign it. You'll have a lot of concurrency problems with your approach.

Comment: @Flavio I am now instantiating both Lock and Condition within the constructor, and not reassigning them. Still getting an IllegalMonitorStateException when calling `signal()`. You can check out the full code here: [http://pastebin.com/bNB9KVSc](http://pastebin.com/bNB9KVSc)

Comment: Third time I write this: you must call `lock.lock()` before `cond.signal()`, and then `lock.unlock()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are not using synchronized block. Here is an example:

```
class MyReader
{
     public int read() throws IOException {  
        int bit = current.read();  
        if (bit == -1 && streams.size() > 0) {  
            // left out due to lacking relevance
        } else if(bit == -1 && streams.size() == 0) {
            waitForNextStream();
            return read();
        }
        return bit;
    }

    private synchronized void waitForNextStream()
    {
        // TODO add close handling, set current here
        while (streams.isEmpty())
        {
            wait();
        }
    }


    public synchronized void addNextStream(InputStream is)
    {
        streams.add(is);
        notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Valeri! Looks pretty good. I assume, I'll have to put the `notify()` inside the `addInputStream()` method in my case. +1 for now...I'll test it ASAP.

Comment: @MCL Do not forget `synchronized` blocks. It will not work without them.

Comment: Okay, I implemented it as you suggested, and it works perfectly. Anyhow, I have some questions: 1. Why are you wrapping the `wait()` in a loop? According to the docs, `wait()` will wait for the next `notify()` anyway. I tried it, and it also works without the loop. 2. I read, that there's some special way of IO blocking when it comes to InputStreams, but could'nt find out what was meant by it. Is this said way or are there other possibilities?

Comment: Check the documentation of `wait()`, you'll find this statement: "[...] interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop".